# Need suggestion to solving logarithm equation of $ \log(\log(x+3))+\log(2) =\log(\log(16x)) $

Tags: logarithms

$$ \log(\log(x+3))+\log(2) =\log(\log(16x))  $$
My work so far is :

Step 1: I using the property of $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(a\times b)$.
Where  $a=\log(x+3)$ and $ b = 2$
$$ \log(2\times \log(x+3))=\log(\log(16x)) $$
Step 2 : I applying anti logarithm.
$$2 \times \log(x+3)=\log(16x)$$
Step 3 : I using the property of $b \times \log(c)=\log(c^b)$.
Where $b=2$ and $c=(x+3)$
$$ \log((x+3)^2)=\log(16x) $$
Step 4 : I applying anti logarithm.
$$(x+3)^2=16x  $$
Step 5 : I expanding the exponent and construct the quadratic form.
$$  x^2+6x+9-16x=0$$
$$ x^2-10x+9=0 $$
Step 6 : I factoring the quadratic form to get two solutions.
$$ (x-1)(x-9)=0 $$
$$ x_1 = 1 \lor x_2= 9$$
Step 7 : I finding the definition term for $\log(\log(x+3))$.
$$ \log(x+3)>0 $$
$$ \log(x+3)>\log(1) $$
$$x+3>1$$
$$x>-2$$
Step 8 : I finding the definition term for $\log(x+3)$.
$$x+3>0$$
$$x>-3$$
Step 9 : I finding the definition term for $\log(\log(16x))$.
$$ \log(16x)>0$$
$$ \log(16x)>\log(1)$$
$$16x>1$$
$$x>\frac{1}{16}$$
Step 10 : I finding the definition term for $\log(16x)$.
$$16x>0$$
$$x>0$$
Step 11 : I making a summary for all definition term.
$$x>\frac{1}{16}$$
Step 12 : I filtering the solutions of equations using the definition term to found the set of solutions
$$x= \{1,9\}$$

Am i do the correct solution for equation above ? I need suggestion and correction if i make a mistake and forget about logarithm property. Thanks for your help,sir.

Comment: No, it' s quite fine. Maybe it's a bit long. For example, rather than using the antilogarithm, I would just  use the  is a bijection from $\mathbf R^{+* }*$ to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Once you have solved the quadratic, you needed to ensure that your solutions are admissible by checking the domain of the original equation (it is $x>\frac1{16}$ as you had calculated). You've done everything correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your derivation of $x=1$ and $x=9$ is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we have

$$\log(\log(x+3))+\log(2) =\log(\log(16x))\iff x^2-10x+9=0$$

with the conditions

- $x+3>1$
- $16x>1$

that is $x>\frac1{16}$ and thus $x= \{1,9\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Personally, I would do the following:

Using logarithmic properties, we have

$\log(\log(x+3)) + \log2 = \log(\log(x+3)\cdot 2).$ We also have by raising $10$ to the power of both sides that  $\log(x+3)\cdot 2=\log(16x).$ Further simplification yields $(x+3)^2=16x.$ And solving gives $x=1$ or $x=9.$ We can plug these values back into the original equation to check if they work, and they do because they're positive.